# How do I rotate service account keys and copy new ones to cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, autorotate

I am trying to automate daily service account key rotation using a function, but not sure how to upload newly created keys to cloud storage and remove old ones.

I have tried the following code, but obviously, it doesn't add to cloud storage bucket. I've also tried incorporating a few gcloud commands into the code, but no luck there either.

```
import logging
import os

import googleapiclient.discovery
from googleapiclient.http import HttpError
from google.cloud import storage

def rotate(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic. This will rotate the
    key on a service account by creating and adding a new key to the configured
    service account and, if successful, deleting any existing keys.

    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('iam', 'v1',
                                              cache_discovery=False)
    service_account_email = os.getenv('key-rotation-function@security-logging-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com')
    bucket_name = 'gs://key-rotation-test'
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    # Create a new key for the service account.
    name = 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + service_account_email
    key = service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().create(
        name=name, body={}).execute()
    new_key = key['name']
    logging.info('Created key: {}'.format(new_key))

    # TODO: update usages of the key here.

    # Delete any other existing keys.
    keys = service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().list(
        name='projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + service_account_email).execute()
    for key in keys['keys']:
        if key['name'] != new_key:
            try:
                service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().delete(
                    name=key['name']).execute()
                logging.info('Deleted old key: {}'.format(key['name']))
            except HttpError as e:
                # Service accounts can have GCP-managed keys which cannot be
                # deleted. This causes a 400 error on the request, so ignore
                # 400 errors.
                if e.resp.status != 400:
                    raise

    return None
```

Comment: `bucket_name` shouldn't include "gs://" in it.  It is just supposed to be the given unique id of the bucket.  You should also be looking for error messages in your output, and include those in your question.  Without an error message that indicates what's going wrong, it'll be pretty hard for people to have an idea how to respond.

Comment: Another item, you do not want to immediately delete service accounts after creating new ones. There should be overlap so that services using existing service accounts continue to work. New service accounts can take a few minutes to provision and become globally available. Unless you are in a top secret environment, rotating keys rapidly is unnecessary. However, you have not explained your use case. Just because you can does not mean you should. Think thru what your real objective is.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'm revising my code and collecting errors, so I will post again soon. Thanks for the feedback.